# Return single String with Flutter sqflite

Tags: flutter, sqflite

This is what I did:

```
Future<String> getMeaning(String word) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    String sql = 'SELECT bn_word FROM words WHERE en_word =?';
    var dbQuery = await dbClient.rawQuery(sql, ['$word']);
    if (dbQuery.length > 0) {
      String defn = dbQuery.first.values.toString();
      return defn;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

The method work but it adds opening `(` and closing `)` to the string. For example, expected to get `apple` but I get `(apple)` instead. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
String defn = dbQuery.first.values.first.toString();
```